# How to model the "sister" relationship so that it implies the gender

Tags: prolog

How can you define mother/father/sister/brother relationships such that asserting `sister(bart, maggie)` makes `?- female(maggie)` evaluate as true?

I'm working on a toy family relation problem.  This is what I have:

```
parent(bart, homer).
parent(bart, marge).
parent(lisa, homer).
parent(lisa, marge).

male(homer).
male(bart).
female(marge).
female(lisa).

mother(X,Y) :- female(Y), parent(X,Y).
father(X,Y) :- male(Y), parent(X,Y).

sister(X,Y) :- female(Y), father(X,F), father(Y,F), mother(X,M), mother(Y,M), X/=Y.
```

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
sister(bart, maggie).

?- female(maggie).
% expect yes
```

i.e. support the "common sense" definition where if you assert that maggie is bart's sister, we know that maggie is female, while still obtaining `sister(bart, lisa)` being true based on the parent/gender assertions I already have.

Comment: So write a rule to support that deduction.  Note that if someone is both asserted to be female explicitly & asserted to be someone's sister, you'll have 2 ways of proving she is female.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your system expects male/female and parent to be a *fact* and derives father/mother/brother/sister through *rules*

You could do this:

```
% X is female if it is somebody's sister.
female(X) :- sister(_,X).
```

But combined with the other rule, it probably won't terminate (X is female if she is sb's sister, she is sb.'s sister if she is female...)

You could set different facts and rules to reverse this way of doing it, e.g. decide that basic facts are sister, mother, son, daughter... But you need to decide what forms elementary information in your database, and what forms derived information. If you want anything to be derived from anything, while staying with simple rules, you quickly end up with a system that doesn't terminate, exploring more and more ways to derive information that is already known.

If you want to have a richer set of inference rules (e.g. if X implies Y and Y is false, then X is false), and make sure your process terminates, doesn't give you the result multiple times, etc, you need to write (or borrow) your own rule interpreter, that is, your own inference engine.

Comment: I think that [tabling](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling) could be useful to (re)gain the generality required and currently missing, but a discussion of the topic would probably drive crazy any newbie. What do you think ?

Comment: tabling helps - though I thought the more important was that to do real inference, we can't stop at depth-first search in an assumed closed world. Once we know there has to be more... We can spend a long time discussing what more.

Answer (score 1):

Common sense reasoning is in general *way* too complex to implement for any general purpose programming language. For this *very* limited domain, we can prototype in SWI-Prolog a simple minded metainterpreter that generalize the goal selection from rules body, and avoids loops by means of tabling:

```erlang
:- autoload(library(tabling)).
:- table solve/1, rule/2.

solve(F) :-
    rule(F,[]).
solve(H) :-
    rule(H,B),
    solve_b(B).

% allowed builtins
solve(X\=Y) :- X\=Y.

solve_b([]).
solve_b(B) :-
    select(G,B,R),
    solve(G),
    solve_b(R).

rule(parent(bart, homer), []).
rule(parent(bart, marge), []).
rule(parent(lisa, homer), []).
rule(parent(lisa, marge), []).

rule(male(homer), []).
rule(male(bart), []).
rule(male(M), [father(_,M)]).
rule(male(M), [brother(_,M)]).

rule(female(marge), []).
rule(female(lisa), []).
rule(female(F), [mother(_,F)]).
rule(female(F), [sister(_,F)]).

rule(mother(X,Y), [female(Y), parent(X,Y)]).
rule(father(X,Y), [male(Y), parent(X,Y)]).

rule(sister(X,Y), [
         female(Y),
         sibling(X,Y)
     ]).
rule(brother(X,Y), [
         male(Y),
         sibling(X,Y)
     ]).

rule(sibling(X,Y), [
         father(X,F),
         father(Y,F),
         mother(X,M),
         mother(Y,M),
         X\=Y
     ]).
rule(sister(bart,maggie), []).
```